# Initialize String in C++

Tags: c++, string, stl

Hi I have a simple c++ program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Rotate this";
    rotate(s.begin(),s.begin()+6,s.end());
    cout<<s<<endl;
    string s1;
    rotate_copy(s.begin(),s.begin()+4,s.end(),s1.begin());
    cout<<s1<<endl;

}
```

This program fails (Runtime Error) since `s1.begin()` iterator points to nothing. How can I initialize the `s1` string so that it is empty and `s.begin()` can be used ?

I know `reserve` can be used i.e. the program works using

```
   string s1;

   s1.reserve(1);
```

but I guess there must be some other way to solve this issue.

Comment: It didn't give runtime error in my PC

Comment: Why the downvote ? It is still gving runtime error .

Comment: Again somebody downvoted ??? Why, is it obvious to everybody the answer ? Using reserve is better or other solutions are ?? Very bad. Do people read question before downvoting or they just read the title ?

Comment: Not that I downvoted, but your claim that it "works using ... `reserve()`" is wrong. Reread carefully the documentation of that function and that of `resize()`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Okay, i will read it. But the program was/is working using reserve(1) and also in Vlad's answer -- undefined behaviour while dereferencing -- I am not dereferencing s.begin().  This question didn't need a downvote, that's why I was ranting. I was just using s.begin() to point to string's location, maybe I guess so it worked. Thanks .

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "dereference" means, it means that the thing that a pointer or iterator refers to is accessed. When rotating, you are writing, which is one of these accesses, and it causes undefined behaviour. Try two things: Firstly, append another character `s += 'x'` and then see what you get. Secondly, find out how to enable diagnostic mode for your compiler and standard library. It would have told you that you are doing something wrong, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should include header `<string>`

```
#include <string>
```

As for `s1` then you should reserve memory for it equal to the size of `s`  and use standard iterator adapter `std::back_insert_ietrator`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "Rotate this";

    std::rotate( s.begin(), std::next( s.begin(), 6 ), s.end() );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::string s1;
    s1.reserve( s.size() );

    std::rotate_copy( s.begin(), std::next( s.begin(), 4 ), s.end(),
                      std::back_inserter( s1 ) );

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
 thisRotate
sRotate thi
```

As for your statement

> I know reserve can be used i.e. the program works using

```
string s1;
s1.reserve(1);
```

then it is wrong. The call of the algorithm will have undefined behaviour because s1 will not have yet elements and you may not dereference the iterator.

Comment: @adrian008 It seems that you do not understand. You do not create new elements of s1. You simply reserve memory for the future elements that will be copied into s1. Now after the reserve s1 is an empty string. Otherwise the  memory will be always reallocated when a new character is copied. reserve is not the same as resize.

Comment: Is reserve the the only way to use a begin() iterator of a new string ? I understood your comment above, its best to use reserve else memory will be reallocated again and again.

Comment: @adrian008 You are going to copy size() characters from string s in string s1. If you will not reserve memory then when the algorithm will copy for example the second character from s to s1 it will reallocate memory because  s1 does not have enough memory that to create the second character. And the memory will be reallocated each time when a next character is copied.

Comment: You can remove the call to `resize()` and it will work just the same. The reason that this works is that `std::back_inserter()` returns an iterator that appends to the end of a container (using `push_back()`), which will create new elements automatically. Reserving enough space up front is an optimization.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), as follows.

```
rotate_copy(s.begin(),s.begin()+4,s.end(),back_inserter(s1));
```

Comment: Why is it better ? Plz explain a bit maybe this is the correct answer. Always  better to write a few lines more than to be lost in being terse :).

Comment: Better in relation to what? It's just an iterator adapter that changes assignment into push_back and changes increment into a no-op. Essentially, what is happening is that a few elements are inserted at the end of the s1 array.